# Error message for HERE isoline calculation

Tags: here-api

I am trying to run isoline routing for a set of 43 locations which are being parsed through a QGIS plugin. The number of valid responses seems to vary, but is never more than around 24 or so.
I'm trying to test what the problem might be by running individual failed locations directly through the API.
My test is "https://isoline.router.hereapi.com/v8/isolines?transportMode=car&Destination=151.7438,-32.7626&range[type]=time&range[values]=420&routingMode=fast&apiKey=XXXX". This gets the message "Isolines could not be calculated" and code IsolineCalculationFailed.
I am not sure what the error is, and would love some advice.

I've tried through a mapping plugin that parses to HERE API.
I've also tried directly through API.
Note that an older version of the API which connects to an older HERE API address (https://isoline.route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?) seems to work successfully with the same/equivalent parameters.